# How to properly parse/decode this byte content to obtain it's string equivalent in pyhon?

Tags: python-3.x, utf-8, hex

Reading through some data, I ran into an isolated case (in my context) where the data does not have the expected format.

The data is read from an email (`.msg` file):

```
msg = extract_msg.Message(file)

print(msg.body.encode("utf-8"))
print(msg.body)
```

The output if this script is the following:

```
b'Bonjour,\r \r \r Je vous invite \xc3\xa0 prendre connaissance des pi\xc3\xa8ces jointes relatives \xc3\xa0 votre dossier r\xc3\xa9f\xc3\xa9renc\xc3\xa9 ci-dessus.\r \r Je vous en souhaite une bonne lecture et reste \xc3\xa0 votre disposition pour tout renseignement compl\xc3\xa9mentaire.\r \r \r Cordialement,\r \r \r name\r othername'
 othername.partofnamehaite une bonne lecture et reste à votre disposition pour tout renseignement complémentaire.
```

As you can see, there are several hex characters as well as many carriage returns. Moreover, the raw body string does not match at all the output of the utf-8 encoded version.

Finally, at the beginning of the second line, note that it contains a (messed up) part of the end of the second line.

I need to retrieve the content of the first line as a string, with expected accents, for example:

```
Bonjour,\r \r \r Je vous invite à prendre connaissance des piéces jointes relatives à votre dossier référencé ci-dessus.\r \r Je vous en souhaite une bonne lecture et reste à votre disposition pour tout renseignement complémentaire.\r \r \r Cordialement,\r \r \r name\r othername
```

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: Please  [edit] your question to share `print(repr(msg.body))` in your [mcve]. Maybe `msg.body.encode( "utf-8")[2:-1].encode( 'raw_unicode_escape').decode( 'unicode_escape').encode( 'latin1').decode( 'utf-8')` could help?

Comment: Looks like `msg.body` is already decoded correctly.  If you `.encode` it, you get the raw bytes of the UTF-8 encoded message.  If you don't want that, don't do that.

Comment: @JosefZ repr(msg.body) has the expected output. There must be something "special" with this particular message...

Comment: @MarkTolonen It is not, at least not in the way I expect it. Check the results of the print. This is not at all the string that I expect to have.

Comment: \r (a carriage return), when printed, moves the print location back to column 1 without a line feed, so parts of the message are overwriting itself. The last thing in the repr is”\r othername” which is the last thing overwritten at the beginning of the printed string.

Comment: `print(msg.body.replace('\r','\n'))` should display it correctly.